# Webapi call is throwing an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, nhibernate

**I have hosted an asp.net webapi project in IIS.The api calls to this project throws an error as mentioned below. The same webapi call works fine when the project is hosted into IIS of another webserver.**

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/datacc")]
    public class DataAccessController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public int HeartBeat()
        {
            return 1;
        }               
}
```

**Error**

```
*[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +9
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +61
   FluentNHibernate.AssemblyTypeSource.GetTypes() in c:\work\coding\fluentNhibernate\src\FluentNHibernate\AssemblyTypeSource.cs:27
   FluentNHibernate.PersistenceModel.AddMappingsFromSource(ITypeSource source) in c:\work\coding\fluentNhibernate\src\FluentNHibernate\PersistenceModel.cs:80
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentMappingsContainer.Apply(PersistenceModel model) in c:\work\coding\fluentNhibernate\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentMappingsContainer.cs:122
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.MappingConfiguration.Apply(Configuration cfg) in c:\work\coding\fluentNhibernate\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\MappingConfiguration.cs:80
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration() in c:\work\coding\fluentNhibernate\src\FluentNHibernate\Cfg\FluentConfiguration.cs:249
[FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
]
   ProjectName2.Data.UnitOfWork..ctor(String databaseConnectionString) in C:\agent\_work\5\s\.....\ProjectName\UnitOfWork.cs:169
ProjectName.WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config) in C:\agent\_work\5\s\.....\ProjectName\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs:66
   System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Action`1 configurationCallback) +27
   ProjectName.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in C:\agent\_work\5\s\....\ProjectName\Global.asax.cs:18
[HttpException (0x80004005): An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +10093921
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +173
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +218
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296
[HttpException (0x80004005): An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.
]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10075124
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254*
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet there is a problem connecting to the database from the new IIS server you are having problems with. This is coming from NHibernate, so it is an issue with the database; however, if it works from one server then it's probably configured correctly. Verify that you can access the database directly from the new IIS server.

Comment: The solution contains three projects. Two webapi projects and one frontend project. These three projects together make our asp.net website. The other webapi project hosted in IIS at same webserver also talks to the  same database and it's not throwing an error at all.

Comment: I also tried connecting to the database from the new webserver and I had no issues at all.

Comment: There must be some difference between your two web api projects. There must be some code replication somewhere that is slightly different in one of the projects. I would recommend moving the NHibernate code in to a 4th project which both API projects call to get data. If that's not feasible right now, copy+paste from the working project to the one that's not working until you figure out what is different. There has to be something in the configuration file or maybe the model if you created the model in both projects.

Comment: I hosted the same webapi project that was throwing an error into another web server and it worked perfectly fine

Comment: The web server which is where the project is throwing an error is brand new. So I am guessing there some dlls missing in the webserver itself.

Comment: Maybe check the versions of .Net between the two servers? If all your packages are coming from NuGet you shouldn't have any mismatch versions except possibly for the framework itself.